# setting text in an array of buttons

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple application in which there are 30 buttons and I need to initialize their text field.
I created this array of buttons:

```
Button[][] buttons_arr = new Button[10][3];
```

To change each button's text I did :

```
for(i=0..9)  //psaudo
  for (j=0..29) //psaudo
    buttons_arr[i][j].setText(toString(some_int));
```

The last line is causing some problems. Why and what can I do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looping in 300 times instead of 30 times

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
for(i=0..9)  //psaudo
      for (j=0..2) //psaudo
        buttons_arr[i][j].setText(""+some_int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Button[][] b=new Button[10][3];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
     {
         b[i][j]=new Button(context);
         b[i][j].setText("something");
     }
}
```

Comment: without declaring "Button Buttons_arr[][] = new Button[10][3]" at the beggining ??

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried 2D arrays. But my experience with a similar problem seems to be that buttons_arr[i][j] is still uninitialized. You need to either create a new button:

```
buttons_arr[1][1] = new Button();
```

or

> buttons_arr[1][1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAtPosition1_1);

Comment: I have this function :
 public void setRandomValuesToButtons() {
  
  for( i=0;i<Rows; i++){
   for( j=0;j<Columns; j++){
    if (i==2 && j==1){
     continue;
    }
      // Random rand = new Random(); rand global variable
    rand_int = rand.nextInt(8);  
    
     
    buttonsTable[i][j]=new Button(this);
    buttonsTable[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(rand_int));
    buttonsVals[i][j]=rand_int;
   }
  }
}

but my buttons doesn't change their text. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        buttons_arr[i][j].setText(your text);
}
```